# How to evaluate $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!(2n+1)!!}}{n+1}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!(2n-1)!!}}{n}\right) $?

Tags: calculus, limits

> for $n$$\in$$N^+$,solve that:
> $$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\left( \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\left( n+1 \right) !\left( 2n+1 \right) !!}}{n+1}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!\left( 2n-1 \right) !!}}{n} \right) $$

i notice double factorials so i try to express it in terms of simple factorials and powers of 2,then it's feasible to use Stirling formula

---

$$f\left( n \right):=\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{\left( n+1 \right) !\left( 2n+1 \right) !!}}{n+1}$$
since $\left( 2n+1 \right) !!=\frac{\left( 2n+1 \right) !}{\left( 2n \right) !!}=\frac{\left( 2n+1 \right) !}{2^nn!}$ and $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \frac{n}{e} \right) ^n$,we have $$f\left( n \right)=\frac{2}{e^2}\left[ 2\pi \left( n+1 \right) \left( 2n+1 \right) \left( n+\frac{1}{4n}+1 \right) ^{2n+1} \right] ^{\frac{1}{2n+2}}$$
hence we should find$$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{2}{e^2}\lim}\left( \left[ 2\pi \left( n+1 \right) \left( 2n+1 \right) \left( n+\frac{1}{4n}+1 \right) ^{2n+1} \right] ^{\frac{1}{2n+2}}-\left[ 2\pi n\left( 2n-1 \right) \left( n+\frac{1}{4n-4} \right) ^{2n-1} \right] ^{\frac{1}{2n}} \right)$$
i guess this can be seen as$$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{2}{e^2}\lim}\left( \left( n+\frac{1}{4n}+1 \right) -\left( n+\frac{1}{4n-4} \right) \right) $$
which equals $\frac{2}{e^2}$.but how to prove it strictly？or is there any approach  better
?

Comment: You may use the following version of Stirling's approximation that holds for any $n \geq 1$
$$>\sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n + 1}} < n! < \sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n}},$$
and then use the Sandwich Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the trick is that
$$A=\left( n+1 \right) !\left( 2n+1 \right) !!=2^{-(n+1)}\, \Gamma (2 n+3)$$
$$B=n!\left( 2n-1 \right) !!=2^{-n}\, \Gamma (2 n+1)$$

Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation for the logarithm of the gamma function
$$\log (\Gamma (p))=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} (\log (2 \pi )-\log (p))+\frac{1}{12   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)  $$
and continue with Taylor
$$\log\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]A}{n+1}\right)=\cdots$$
Now, Taylor again using
$$\frac{\sqrt[n+1]A}{n+1}=\exp\left(\log\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]A}{n+1}\right) \right)=\cdots$$

Doing the same with the second piece, you should end with
$$\frac 2 {e^2} \left(1+\frac 1 {2n}+O\left(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)$$

The next term would be ugly

Answer (score 2):

Let $$a_n=\frac{\sqrt[n] {n! (2n-1)!!}}{n}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}{2n}$$ It is well known that $\sqrt[n] {n! }/n\to 1/e$ and hence  $$\frac{\sqrt [n]{(2n)!}}{4n^2}=\frac{a_n} {2n}\to \frac {1}{e^2}$$ Further we can observe that $$b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(2n+2)!}}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}=\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\sqrt[n]{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\cdot((2n+2)!) ^{-1/n(n+1)}$$ and one can prove that the above expression tends to $1$.

Then we have $$a_{n+1}-a_n=a_n\left(\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)=\frac{a_n}{2n}\cdot\frac{b_n-1}{\log b_n} \cdot 2n\log b_n$$ and the middle fraction tends to $1$ so that the limit in question equals the limit of $$\frac{a_n}{2n}\cdot 2n(\log a_{n+1}-\log a_n) $$ Since $a_n/(2n)\to 1/e^2$ our job is done if we show that $$2n(\log a_{n+1}-\log a_n)\to 2$$ Now $$2n(\log a_{n+1}-\log a_n)=-2n\log(1+(1/n))+2\log(2n+1)(2n+2)-\frac{2}{n+1}\log(2n+2)!$$ Since the first term tends to $-2$ our job is done if we show that $$\log(2n+1)(2n+2)-\frac{1}{n+1}\log (2n+2)!\to 2$$ This is equivalent to proving that $$\log(2n-1)(2n)-\frac{1}{n}\log(2n)!=\log\frac{2n(2n-1)}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}=\log\frac{2n-1}{a_n}$$ tends to $2$. Now $a_n/(2n)\to 1/e^2$ so it follows that above expression tends to $2$.